# VSCode Setting (Does it exist)

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I perform a deploy or retrieve operation in VSCODE the result of the operation will make the panel that shows the output appear. I perform deploy and retrieve operations frequently since I use the "deploy on save" functionality. Is there a setting that will prevent that panel from showing up if the result of the operation is a success? Basically I only want the panel to show up if there is an actual problem that needs my attention/focus.

The below image shows the panel I am referring to circled in blue. The panel covers my code and requires that I manually click a button to rehide it.

I've tried turning the panel off in the "VIEW" settings but that doesn't work.

I've tried resizing it so that the height is very small but that is equally as annoying when I actually need to open the panel to use the terminal or review errors from the deploy/retrieve.

**Is there a setting in VSCode that will prevent that panel from showing when the operation is successful?**

NOTE: For every retrieve/deploy there is a dialog box that says if the operation was a success or failure. So not having this panel show will not prevent the user from knowing how the operation resulted

[image: Shows the panel covering code]

Comment: Related discussion [ Don't focus Output Panel #1110 ](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/1110)

Comment: @rochard4u thanks for posting that. There is good information in the chat feed. It definitely is related but not quite the same issue.